# CouchDB Finnish/Swedish collation view

Tags: sorting, couchdb, collation

How can I change a CouchDB view collation to sort skandinavian letters (åäö) after z?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't configure it unfortunately. The collation for CouchDB is implemented via the [ICU library](http://site.icu-project.org/) which **does** have the facility to provide alternative collations, both from a locale DB and totally custom rules.

Unfortunately CouchDB does not expose any of that, [its `ucol_open` call](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-couch/blob/master/priv/icu_driver/couch_icu_driver.c#L62) has a hardcoded `""` value for the locale.

As it stands, in order to customize this for your locale, you would need to recompile CouchDB passing a value for that locale parameter to `ucol_open`, [more info on the format etc of that is available here](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ucol_8h.html#a4721e4c0a519bb0139a874e191223590).